# Keras: Error when checking input

Tags: keras, theano, autoencoder

I am using Keras autoencodes with Theano backend. And want to make autoencode for 720x1080 RGB images.
This is my code

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, RepeatVector, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from keras.models import Model

from PIL import Image


x_train = []
x_train_noisy = []

for i in range(5,1000):
    image = Image.open('data/trailerframes/frame' + str(i) + '.jpg', 'r')
    x_train.append(np.array(image))
    image = Image.open('data/trailerframes_avg/frame' + str(i) + '.jpg', 'r')
    x_train_noisy.append(np.array(image))


x_train = np.array(x_train)
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_train_noisy = np.array(x_train_noisy)
x_train_noisy = x_train_noisy.astype('float32') / 255.


input_img = Input(shape=(720, 1080, 3))
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), data_format="channels_last", activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), data_format="channels_last", activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), data_format="channels_last", activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

autoencoder.fit(x_train_noisy, x_train,
            epochs=10,
            batch_size=128,
            shuffle=True,
            validation_data=(x_train_noisy, x_train))
```

But it gives me an error

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_7 to have shape (None, 720, 1080, 3) but got array with shape (995, 720, 1280, 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Input error:**

As simple as:

- You defined your input as (720,1080,3)
- You're trying to trian your model with data in the form (720,1280,3)

One of them is wrong, and I think it's a typo in the input:

```
#change 1080 for 1280
input_img = Input(shape=(720, 1280, 3))
```

**Output error (target):**

Now, your target data is shaped like (720,1280,3), and your last layer outputs (720,1280,1)

A simple fix is:

```
decoded = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), data_format="channels_last", activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
```

**Using the encoder:**

After training that model, you can create submodels for using only the encoder or the decoder:

```
encoderModel = Model(input_img, decoded)    

decoderInput = Input((shape of the encoder output))    
decoderModel = Model(decoderInput,decoded))
```

These two models will share the exact same weights of the entire model, training one model will affect all three models.

For using them without training, you can use `model.predict(data)`, which will give you the results without training.

Comment: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_78 to have shape (None, 720, 1280, 1) but got array with shape (995, 720, 1280, 3)

Comment: Now you've changed 3 for 1.... you've got to have the same shape for both sides of that message.

Comment: Where I changed 3 for 1 ? I just changed 1080 to 1280 in input shape

Comment: Read the message in your comment. It says (None, 720, 1280, `1`), it should be `3`.

Comment: Ok . I understand :) but I dont use any 1 in my code. Maybe it is from Conv2D ?

Comment: Ah, my bad, sorry! Now the error is talking about "target", this is the output instead of the input. It's another error. Will update answer....

Comment: Not it works. Thank you :) 
Can you suggest me more complex example of keras autoencoders ? 
I found only mnist data based autoencoder examples, and cant find more

Comment: I don't know examples :( --- But you can do that with anything -- Create layers (any kind of layer, any number, shape, etc.) that reduce your data to some weird array (the `encoded` tensor in your model). Then create layers that follow the inverse path until you output the same as the input. (after  `encoded` until `decoded`) .

Comment: Added a little about using the encoder and the decoder.