# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_input

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, time-series, lstm

My data just contains just 30 rows. I have attached the screenshots of my data. I need to predict the 31st value with pervious 30 vaues in pow column in that data screenshot

[image]

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
# from keras.models import Sequential
# from keras.layers import Dense
# from keras.layers import LSTM
# from keras.layers import Dropout
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout



data_training = pd.read_csv('G:\Agrima\Obj_Rec\power.csv')

data_training = data_training.iloc[:, 2:3].values


scaler = MinMaxScaler()
data_training = scaler.fit_transform(data_training)

print(data_training[0:10])


X_train = []
y_train = []

for i in range(10, data_training.shape[0]):
    X_train.append(data_training[i-10:i])
    y_train.append(data_training[i, 0])

X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)

print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)

regressior = Sequential()

regressior.add(LSTM(units = 60, activation = 'relu', return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[0], 5)))
regressior.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressior.add(LSTM(units = 60, activation = 'relu', return_sequences = True))
regressior.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressior.add(LSTM(units = 80, activation = 'relu', return_sequences = True))
regressior.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressior.add(LSTM(units = 120, activation = 'relu'))
regressior.add(Dropout(0.2))

regressior.add(Dense(units = 1))

print(regressior.summary())

regressior.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')

regressior.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=32)

regressior.save_weights('my_model_weights.h5') #Dude this is imp.. Dont train each time.. Try googling how to load weight..or call me

#input new values to get new predicitons
new = 62 #this must be input of the last day data da --- like this it shld be : new = data_training[-1]
inputs = scaler.transform(new)
y_pred = regressior.predict(input)
print(y_pred)


# Visualising the results
plt.figure(figsize=(14,5))
plt.plot(X_train, color = 'red', label = 'Real Data')
plt.plot(y_pred, color = 'blue', label = 'Predicted Data')
plt.title('Power')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Power')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Error log :

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_input to have
>   shape (20, 5) but got array with shape (10, 1)

Comment: C'mon ! People who wants to dislike the question please mind typing down why you did so! Or at least try helping solve them. You guys don't know the answer but still goes degrading the question that may help some other.

Comment: Check input shape and try to reshape it with the given shape (20,5) or send me file and will try to tell you the correct input_shape. look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944981/keras-error-when-checking-input

Comment: @ahmedemad Thanks for response. I solved it ! :)